# Were any Expanded Universe vehicles besides the Juggernaut made canon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

The [HAVw A5 Juggernaut](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HAVw_A6_Juggernaut/Legends) was an Expanded Universe wheeled vehicle that appears in the Essential Guide to Vehicles and Vessels, and presumably one of the books or games that I don't recall. It actually began its life as a production sketch for one of the original films (iirc, a design for the Empire's war machines on Hoth, a role that ended up going to the AT-AT) at which time it didn't even have a name.

Fast forward around 3 decades, and ILM included a shot of the Juggernaut (presumably working off of the original production sketch) in one of the prequel films (I forget if it was AOTC or ROTS), thus officially making it (or at least its design) canon.

Have any other expanded universe vehicles (whether planet-based craft or spacecraft) appeared in the films and become canon? ([This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/did-george-lucas-use-any-of-the-expanded-universe-material-in-the-prequel-trilog) partially addresses my question but doesn't even mention the Juggernaut)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.** [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_expanded_universe#Cameo_appearances), a few EU vehicles are included in the special editions and prequels:

- A swoop bike, from Shadows of the Empire, is seen scaring a Ronto in Mos Eisley in the special edition of A New Hope:
  [image]
- A YT-2400 freighter, possibly Dash Rendar's Outrider from Shadows of the Empire, is (barely, at far left) seen taking off from Mos Eisley in the special edition of A New Hope:
  [image]
  Its characteristic shape can be seen a bit more clearly later in the shot:
  [image]
- An Action VI transport (the same model as Talon Karrde's Wild Karrde) is seen (barely, at lower right) on Naboo in Attack of the Clones:
  [image]
  While it's barely visible in the full frame, its silhouette is distinguishable on close examination:
  [image]

Wikipedia also notes that the Sentinel-class Imperial landing craft, which first appeared in Shadows of the Empire, was originally designed for inclusion in the special edition of A New Hope. So that's a borderline case, since it was intended to be canon from the start.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking this as the answer, I never received a notification that anyone had responded to this question. Extremely useful, thank you! I see a YT-1400 also makes a cameo in the Naboo shot. That reddish craft **can't be a Legends Action VI** - its shape doesn't match any of the official images of the Action VI closely enough - but perhaps it's another craft from the same line, or maybe ILM has officially changed the appearance of the vessel.

Comment: Wouldn't the YT-1300 owner's manual be considered canon now, since upon closer inspection if the fourth image you see a variation of a YT-1300 sitting on the left side of the space port.

Comment: @CBredlow - I don't think that's a YT-1300. It definitely looks like a design from the same manufacturer, but doesn't have the round cockpit module on the right side like a 1300 or 2400 does.

Comment: @Omegacron that's why asked about the owners manual. There they list out different variations and one of them looked similar to that.

Comment: The Interdictor cruiser that prevents ships from going to lightspeed originated in the SW roleplaying game (specifically "The Imperial Sourcebook", 1989) and was later featured in the _Rebels_ animated series (although that's a TV show, not a movie). Interestingly, swoop bikes were also first described in the roleplaying game ("The Star Wars Sourcebook", 1987) which predates _Shadows Of The Empire_ (1996). However, the specific design of swoop bike shown in ANH:SE might have originated in the video game.